# How to keep order of values while adding them to JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I need to generate a JSON from a list of objects. To do it I am using the following code, but I have two problems:

1. The order of entries get changes
2. It adds `\` before all `"` when I show the JSON.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
for (Row row : rows) {
    jsonObj.put(row.getCode(),row.getValue());

}
myJson.put(jsonObj.toString());
System.err.println("myJson:" + myJson.toString());
```

**Output**

```
myJson:["{\"1234445\":\"Jack"}"]
```

Thanks to  Sotirios Delimanolis , after removing .toString() from jsonObj the first problem has been solved.

Comment: Do you know what `jsonObj.toString()` does? Why are you using that?

Comment: Please review the JSON format [here](http://json.org/).

Comment: The order of the entries in a JSON document doesn't matter.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch in a JSON _Object_; order is defined for JSON Arrays

Comment: @fge Then what does OP mean by *the order of entries get changes*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch my guess is that the implementation serializes to a `Map` implementation which has no defined iteration order; which leads to the JSON being potentially "different" from one run to another; except that, of course, it isn't according to the RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have used in our project to get the order of Json array using comparator. 
I am posting the same you just use you array according to your elements it.

GetSortedList is a method  that array accepts an array and returns the list which is sorted.
@

```
               List<JsonElement> lJaArray = null;
               lJaArray = getSortedList( lJaArrayUnsorted ); // theJson    array you want to sort.
```

public static List getSortedList( JsonArray array ) throws JSONException
    {
        List list = new ArrayList();
        for( int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++ )
        {
            list.add( array.get( i ) );
        }
        Collections.sort( list,
                          new Comparator()
                          {

`@Override
                          public int compare( JsonElement o1,
                                  JsonElement o2 )
                          {

                              if( Integer.parseInt( o1.getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "com.tangoe.matrix.catalog.CatalogFeatureDetail" )
                                      .getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "order" )
                                      .toString()
                                      .replace( "\"",
                                                "" ) ) > Integer.parseInt( o2.getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "com.tangoe.matrix.catalog.CatalogFeatureDetail" )
                                      .getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "order" )
                                      .toString()
                                      .replace( "\"",
                                                "" ) ) )
                              {
                                  return 1;
                              }
                              else if( Integer.parseInt( o1.getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "com.tangoe.matrix.catalog.CatalogFeatureDetail" )
                                      .getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "order" )
                                      .toString()
                                      .replace( "\"",
                                                "" ) ) < Integer.parseInt( o2.getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "com.tangoe.matrix.catalog.CatalogFeatureDetail" )
                                      .getAsJsonObject()
                                      .get( "order" )
                                      .toString()
                                      .replace( "\"",
                                                "" ) ) )
                              {
                                  return -1;
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  return 0;
                              }

                          }
                      } );

    return list;

}`

I have posted my elements Just replace your array elements in it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

From [RFC 7159, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4):

> JSON parsing libraries have been observed to differ as to whether or
> not they make the ordering of object members visible to calling
> software.  Implementations whose behavior does not depend on member
> ordering will be interoperable in the sense that they will not be
> affected by these differences.

Your implementation seems to be one of those "interoperable" ones; order of object members do not matter.

Which means it may serialize an object with members a, b, c so that you iterate them as b, a, c; nothing you can do about it, except customizing your object member order yourself.